# The @aws-amplify/react-native dependency causes React Native to not compile on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify

I've got a React Native app and I'm attempting to use AWS Amplify to manage push notifications.

AWS Amplify has so far been great for auth via Cognito.

I can't get the app to compile when I try to set up push notifications, though.

I'm following these instructions:

https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/push-notifications/set-up-push-notifications/

But the `@aws-amplify/react-native` library is causing problems. When I try to compile and run the app on iOS after adding that library via npm, I get:

````
- Building the app.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace GlobeThrivers.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme GlobeThrivers -destination id=E49400FA-5645-4B20-BC5A-48B1D68606E4

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (83 targets)
    Target 'GlobeThrivers' in project 'GlobeThrivers'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-GlobeThrivers' in project 'Pods' via file 'libPods-GlobeThrivers.a' in build phase 'Link Binary'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'AmplifyRTNCore' in project 'Pods' via options '-lAmplifyRTNCore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'AmplifyRTNPushNotification' in project 'Pods' via options '-lAmplifyRTNPushNotification' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'AmplifyUtilsNotifications' in project 'Pods' via options '-lAmplifyUtilsNotifications' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lCocoaAsyncSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-lDoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Boost-iOSX' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Fmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-PeerTalk' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FlipperKit' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipperKit' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Mixpanel-swift' in project 'Pods' via options '-lMixpanel-swift' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'MixpanelReactNative' in project 'Pods' via options '-lMixpanelReactNative' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCT-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNAWSCognito' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNAWSCognito' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCAsyncStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCMaskedView' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCMaskedView' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCPicker' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCPicker' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFastImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFastImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNKeychain' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNKeychain' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNSVG' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNSVG' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Core' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-NativeModulesApple' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-NativeModulesApple' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAppDelegate' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-debug' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-debug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-hermes' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-hermes' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsi' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsiexecutor' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsiexecutor' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsinspector' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsinspector' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-logger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-logger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-perflogger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-perflogger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-runtimescheduler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-runtimescheduler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-utils' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-utils' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactNativeUiLib' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReactNativeUiLib' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SDWebImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lSDWebImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SDWebImageWebPCoder' in project 'Pods' via options '-lSDWebImageWebPCoder' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SocketRocket' in project 'Pods' v
[error] npm run ios_large Failed
[error] ios_large Failed.```

I'm totally out of ideas about how to get around this. Any ideas?
````